# Why is IE6 sending me NULL characters (0x00) as JSON POST data?

Tags: json, internet-explorer, http, jquery

I've got an occasional exception in my (C#) server code when trying to deserialize JSON data sent from jQuery.ajax().  The POST data is entirely NULL characters (in binary, 0x00).  I record all POST data from errors in my log and in text mode, it looks like spaces:

```
"          "
```

But in binary mode, it is:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

This exact same error has been logged 3 times, from the same user, separated by roughly 15 minutes.

What could be going on?  I've Googled and found nothing like this.

Here's the actual error from the JSON deserializer:

```
System.ArgumentException:  Invalid JSON primitive: .
    at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
    at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
    at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
```

User agent:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.2)
```

Content type:

```
application/json
```

Another clue: in our global error handler, we try to write a response message to the user (like "Sorry you had a problem, we're looking into it.").  When we tried to do this for this user, every time we had this same exception:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
```

Here's how we are reading the data (I've had to copy/paste in some of our library code):

```
[Ajax]
[AsyncTimeout(300001)] // 5 minutes
[ValidateInput(false)] // We want to pass in XML via POST
public void CommandAsync()
{
    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

    // Reads the main body of a request, without closing the
    // stream.  The advantage of not closing the stream is that it can
    // be re-read later, particularly by the Global.asax.cs error
    // handler.
    // It seems that if the content type is not form-url-encoded
    // then the input stream needs to be reset.  Weird.
    Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    byte[] content = new byte[Request.ContentLength];
    Request.InputStream.Read(content, 0, Request.ContentLength);
    string dataStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content);

    if (dataStr.Length != 0) {
        var data = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(dataStr);

        // do something with data
    }
}
```

**[Edit]**

Eric was right in that IE sent no data in the stream.

So the solution for us is to shrink the array down to whatever was read:

```
    int content_length = request.ContentLength;
    byte[] content = new byte[content_length];
    int read = request.InputStream.Read(content, 0, content_length);
    if (read < content_length)
        Array.Resize(ref content, read);
```

Or alternatively, we could have simply used StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd() and it would have been a bit less efficient, but would have never have had this bug.

Comment: How are you getting the data into your C#? Often errors like this are caused by using an array or memorystream which hasn't been fully filled (e.g. because the client sent less data than expected).

Comment: @EricLaw good point!  I have added my data reading code.

Comment: Reading over my own code, I really should be using Request.ContentEncoding instead of UTF8.  Could that have caused this issue?  I assume older browsers would send ASCII + extended codepage chars, which UTF8 would decode as gobbledygook instead of NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Eric, you were right!

When AJAX post requests were cancelled in Internet Explorer, it still sent them to the server, but with no actual content and with an incorrect content length in the header.

We read the content using:

```
request.InputStream.Position = 0;
byte[] content = new byte[request.ContentLength];
request.InputStream.Read(content, 0, request.ContentLength);
```

it created a byte array of \0's because there was no content to overwrite the initialized array.